# Output rendering in Mozilla different

Tags: html, formatting

I'm playing with a new layout of the site and I am getting quite hopeless in chrome and opera everything renders the way it should be but in Mozilla I get unformated output from PHP that is causing this and how to fix this.
I have put everything in a fixed cell but it is somehow ignored:

```
<td width="900px"> <div id="dynamiclist_index"><?php echo $dynamic_list;?></div></td>
```

The site is: http://musetemplatespro.com/.

Comment: what are the all the css you're using for `<td>` and `<div>`?

Comment: td-none div- thied to apply width 900px it shows as active but has no effect in mozila

Answer (score 0):

but would not recommend putting styles in div's or td best to create separate stylesheet

```
<td style="width:900px;"> 
<td style="width:900px; margin: 0px auto;">
```

style sheet:

```
.container {width: 900px margin: 0px auto;}
```

best to have a container example

```
<div class="container">
<div id="dynamiclist_index">
<td><?php echo $dynamic_list;?></td>
</div>
</div>
```

it may work or not

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a single table for each output.
It is better if you use it like this:

```
<table width="900" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<?php foreach($your_values as $value){ ?>
   <tr style="width:300; float:left;">
      <td>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="product.php?id=3"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="images/theme_pic/3/3.jpg" alt="3" width="300" height="400" border="1"></a></li>
            <li><a style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  font-weight: lighter;   ">1</a></li>
            <li><hr></li>
         </ul>
      </td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

There will be need of more styling but this is safer for cross-browser compatibility